# How to create a type alias for a nested static method in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In a library I have a number of namespaces with classes and I wonder if I can create a type alias to static methods in such classes.

Let's assume something like this:

```js
export namespace ns1 {
    export namespace ns2 {
        export class A {
            public static log(text: string) {
                console.log(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In another file I import ns1 and what to define a type alias to the log method:

```js
import { ns1 } from "./";

type log = ns1.ns2.A.log;
```

and use it as if it was a local function:

```js
log("Hello World");
```

What's required to make this work?

Comment: You don't want a *type* alias, types don't exist at runtime and can't be called as functions.   What's wrong with `const log = ns1.ns2.A.log;` instead as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wR0YEm)? (...which seems... obvious? to the point where this feels like a typo.)  Also, `export ns1 {  export ns2 { ...` is invalid TypeScript, so presumably you want `namespace` there or something?  How should we proceed here?

Comment: I've never worked much with namespaces, but you need to use brackets notation and string literals for accessing properties on types, and the `A` type is for *instances* (`typeof A` is the constructor function's type). So that part of it would be `(typeof A)["log"]` (you don't actually need the `()`, but I've included them for clarity). **But:** *"and use it as if it was a local function"* Then you don't need a type at all, you need a local variable/constant. Types don't exist at runtime (other than that enums have a small footprint).

Comment: @jcalz I knew there was a better way, which is why I asked. Using a type alias was obviously a wrong idea, but good enough to explain what I'm after. Care to create an answer I can accept?

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance.

Comment: I don't think this question is worth answering; it is just based on a confusion between types and variables (or constants). But it is unlikely that the question will be found by people with the same confusion, and there must be an existing Q&A that addresses the difference between types and variables/constants.

Comment: @kaya3 I dare to disagree. If your argument would be valid then half of the questions on Stackoverflow have to be closed, as they started from wrong assumptions. Also, there are many questions here that ask why something doesn't work and it turned out they had a typo. Questions like this help people (like me) that start with a wrong assumption to find the real solution.

Comment: I think the question isn't "caused by a typo" but I'm still not convinced it's worthwhile to have it open. The main reason to reopen would be that other people trying to do the same thing would find this question when searching... but the term "type alias" is essentially unrelated to what you want.  The only reason I understood what you wanted was the combination of `import { ns1 } from "./";` and `log("Hello World");`. Talk of type aliases was an impediment for me, not a help. Maybe you could [edit] to make it less of an XY problem? Anyway I'm not sure what should/can be done from here.

Comment: I couldn't care less, since I have my solution, but that's not how I think. I still believe this question would be useful for others, but I have no strong feelings either, so let's keep it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about how to alias a long qualifier to a local name that can be used instead. This is useful for libraries that are organized in nested namespaces and/or classes.

In TypeScript you have to differentiate between types and values. Types are erased at runtime. This may require to create two different aliases for a qualified name, depending on what it is and how it is used. Assume you have a (generic) class `ArrayList`, located in the `java.util` namespace.

You have to create two aliases:

```js
const ArrayList = java.util.ArrayList;
type ArrayList<T> = java.util.ArrayList<T>;
```

The first alias (aka. "constant reassignment" or "variable renaming") is necessary if you want to create an instance of the class. It does not take any type parameter, as it is really just another name for the same value.

The second one is for use as a type, e.g.

```js
const test: ArrayList<number>;
```

An alternative way to define the type "alias" is to use the constant reassignment like this:

```js
const ArrayList = java.util.ArrayList;
type ArrayList<T> = InstanceType<typeof ArrayList<T>>;
```

which is a bit more expressive, but might be useful in certain cases.

To actually answer the question (which mostly refers to defining an alias for a member of a class) use what @jcalz already mentioned:

```
const log = ns1.ns2.A.log;
```

You can then use the local name instead of the fully qualified name, e.g. `log("Hello World")`.

**Note:** a reassignment of class methods only works for static methods and depending on your linter settings you may get an error about an unbound method (even though it's static), recommending to use an arrow function.